# SMS API Integration with PHP and data from MySQL

Tags: php, api

I have below php API code for sending sms for my customers. **The users are stored in Database. How can retrieve users from Database and pass values to PHP API code.**

**Note**: Tested from html form, If i pass single mobile no from html form sms is working For 2 users below code getting error

> {"errors":[{"code":4,"message":"No recipients
>   specified"}],"status":"failure"}

```
<?php

 $mobile1=$_POST["mobile1"]; //Example user from html form
 $mobile2=$_POST["mobile2"]; //Example user from html form
 $msgtxt=$_POST["msgtxt"];
       if(isset($_POST['btn1_send_msg']))
            {

    $apiKey = urlencode('myapiKey-ublQN4O2BcRPxXme8wvw2hzHzCpa');

// Message details

// $numbers = urlencode($mobile1); // is working
    $numbers = urlencode($mobile1,$mobile2);  //This is not working,I need mobile no from MySQL Database
    $sender = urlencode('PM-4STEC');
    $message = rawurlencode($msgtxt);

// Prepare data for POST request
    $data = 'apikey=' . $apiKey . '&numbers=' . $numbers . "&sender=" . 
    $sender . "&message=" . $message;

// Send the GET request with cURL    
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.my-messagegatewayapi.com/send/?' . $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

// Process your response here
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you please cross check, for multiple number you have the same api parameters or not? Sometimes parameters are different to allow multiple number

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass two parameters to `urlencode` try this :

```
$numbers = urlencode($mobile1).','.urlencode($mobile2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother firstly you have to check your API would work for 2 numbers simultaneously. Because when you pass one number it is working.

Comment: //Two mobile nos are working as passing value directly like this                       
 $numbers = urlencode('100012345,1234567890');

Answer (score 0):

It seems that variables are empty coming from the form.

```
$mobile1=$_POST["mobile1"]; //Example user from html form
$mobile2=$_POST["mobile2"];
```

can you do:

```
echo "$mobile1 $mobile2";
```

Also I don't see the SQL part